# Java GeoTools read VRT file

Tags: gdal, java, geotools, vrt

I am trying to read a GDAL VRT file.

I have included

```
    <!-- VRT Format (reader) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-imageio-ext-gdal</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I have these files:

```
VRTFormat
VRTFormatFactory
VRTReader
```

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/669897d2778dab8c31e7ad97bf16ae02e885bfa1/modules/plugin/imageio-ext-gdal/src/main/java/org/geotools/coverageio/gdal/vrt

but

```
 AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat("...");
 GridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader("...");
```

causes Exception

```
Trying to get a reader from an unknown format.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Trying to get a reader from an unknown format.
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.UnknownFormat.getReader(UnknownFormat.java:62)
```

how to enable GeoTools to find the respective VRT reader?

Comment: do you have imageio installed? specifically, you need `it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.vrt.VRTImageReaderSpi`

Comment: yes, I have `it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.vrt.VRTImageReaderSpi`

Comment: how are you building and running your app?

Comment: Maven: I have included all dependecies including the `gt-imageio-ext-gdal`

Comment: turn logging up to Fine - I'm seeing "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gdal.gdalconst.gdalconstConstants"

Comment: I guess the problem roots are deeper. At first, I thought that GeoTools impelements a Java-native VRT reader. I tried to instantiate `VRTReader` explicitly but experienced an the expcetion `Failed to load gdaljni`. This means that GeoTools relies on gdal native libs. I did not find a convinient Maven way to include gdal libs for a platform. GeoTools site tells that ImageIO has a java-gdal binding and contains a broken link to java.net but whether that binding is worth searching and trying, is it up to date? Is their a way to set up native gdal libs via Maven?

Comment: best description of process is http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#installing-gdal-native-libraries